# $location.hash and $anchorScroll(); without hash in the URL

Tags: angularjs

Based on what is written on [$anchorScroll Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll), I should be able to scroll to a hash without updating the URL (and without changing the route), but it seems I'm not able to do it.

If I write

```
$scope.myFunction = function(id) {
  $location.hash(id);
  $anchorScroll();
```

I get the hash and the scroll and the route changes.

If I write

```
$scope.myFunction = function(id) {
  $anchorScroll(id);
```

I don't get the hash in the URL, and the scroll too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: let's say you want to scroll to a div tag with id "thatDiv", on click of a link.  Assuming you have a function ng-click="goToThatDiv()".  you could write this code:  $scope.goToThatDiv = function() {
  $location.hash("thatDiv");
  $anchorScroll();  // here you don't specify the div id again.  it is //specified once and you leave it like that.

/* that's all.  Note you need to have injected $location, $anchorScroll into the controller, that has the method goToThatDiv ,which is dependency injection as you should know.*/
});

Comment: I've just tried a thing and something weird happened: my code is now `$timeout((function() {$anchorScroll(inserzione.titolo);}), 0);` and it's working as exptected, scrolling.. what the hell is going on?

Comment: it has to be said that $anchorScroll() is called after an ng-show/hide, but ehy, is that process so long that it's needed to wait a $timeout with 0ms delay?

Comment: As it is documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for controllers - "The recommended way of declaring Controllers is using the array notation", with $scope and the dependencies as array elements and function parameters.  If you really want to know what is going behind the scene, may be refer to [toddmotto annotation process](https://toddmotto.com/angular-js-dependency-injection-annotation-process/).

Comment: I think we're not talking about the same thing.. I know I have to do certain things in order to use Angular and not just write some code like vanilla js, I was just wondering about why that delay is needed..